# IEEE 802.1Q performance (VLAN tagging)

Tags: cisco, vlan

What is the performance impact of VLAN tagging with Cisco Catalyst 3750G. Is the slowdown noticeable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about that specific switch, but generally VLAN tagging is done in hardware when the packet is switched, so should not be a performance impact at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mike. I though the same that there is no impact on perforfmance but wanna be sure. I need to implement tagging on vmware environment

Comment: @Alan: of course, if you are going to trunk many VLANs on the same connection, the total bandwidth will be shared between them; other than that, tagging *per se* should have no impact at all.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm mike answer, tagging is done by ASICs and have almost no impact on performance